# How to get Top 10 rows from a sorted DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I want to get top 10 rows from a DataTable in the same order as the previous DataTable.

With the code I have below, I can have it sorted in dt1 and import only 10 rows into dt2 but it's not importing the rows in the sorted order. I need it to keep the sorted order. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
    DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone(); 
    dt1.DefaultView.Sort = "x DESC"; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        dt2 .ImportRow(dt1.Rows[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a query and sorting like this:

```
DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();

//get only the rows you want
DataRow[] results = dt.Select("", "x DESC");

//populate new destination table
for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)        
    dt2.ImportRow(results[i]);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It is throwing this error Syntax error: Missing operand after '10' operator.

Comment: Sorry, I used the incorrect code. I've edited it, see if it works for you now.

Comment: Thanks for editing it, Now it's throwing this Syntax error: Missing operand after 'DESC' operator.

Comment: I was editing and it saved before I had finished. Oops.. just fixed it (again) just need to do the select like this: `DataRow[] results = dt.Select("", "x DESC");`

Comment: @TomWijsman the `Clone` only copies the DataTable's schema: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You're sorting the *view* of the data, not the data itself; thus, when you access the rows, it is the *unsorted* data you are once again accessing.

You need to get a sorted set of rows from dt1 using Select(), and then take the rows from *that*.

Comment: Yes I was trying to select but I was getting the syntax wrong dt1.Select("x Desc");. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
void GetSortedTable(int count, string order = "DESC")
{
    // Get our data table sorted by 'x' in a specific 'order'.
    DataRow[] results = dt.Select("", "x " + order);

    // Create a new empty data table.
    DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();

    // Import the resulting 'count' rows into it.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        dt2.ImportRow(results[i]);

    return dt2;
}
```

**Related:** [MSDN - DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx)