# select top 5 records from xml with C#

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

Hello everyone i wanna to fetch the top 5 records from xml file in asp.net.. Please tell me how can i do that i am fetching the data like this from xml

Here is my repeator Markup i am binding my data with eval tag in repeator

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
  <!-- content -->

      <div class="post">
        <div class="right">
          <h2><a href="#">
              <asp:Label ID="lbltitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title ") %>'></asp:Label></a></h2>
            <asp:Label ID="lblcontent" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Discription") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="left">

          <p class="dateinfo">
          <asp:Label ID="lbldate"
                  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DT") %>'></asp:Label>
              <span><asp:Label ID="lblmnth" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("mnt") %>'></asp:Label></span></p>
          <div class="post-meta">
            <h4>Post Info</h4>
            <ul>
              <li class="user"><a href="#">Erwin</a></li>
              <li class="time"><a href="#">12:30 PM</a></li>
              <li class="comment">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/PostComment.aspx"   >Comments</asp:HyperLink></li>
              <li class="permalink"><a href="#">Permalink</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

C# code

```
 var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Data/BlogContent.xml"));
    var result = doc.Descendants("post").Where(x => x.Element("id") != null).Select(x => new
    {
        id = x.Element("id").Value,
        title = x.Element("title").Value,
        Description = x.Element("Discription").Value,
        dt = x.Element("dt").Value,
        mnt = x.Element("mnt").Value,
        yr = x.Element("yr").Value
    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(5);
    Repeater1.DataSource = result;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Top 10 rows from a sorted DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752871/how-to-get-top-10-rows-from-a-sorted-datatable)

Comment: Can you show your XML

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <post>
  </post>

  <post>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>fds</title>
    <Discription>fdsafsdf</Discription>
    <dt>21</dt>
    <mnt>6</mnt>
    <yr>2013</yr>
  </post>
</content>

Comment: @azadc I have updated my post with your XML. You have 3 examples, a generic one, to bind the result with a data grid, and also one using your own XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LINQ - Having seen XML now, added a where to allow for null posts

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\test.xml");
var result = doc.Descendants("post").Where(x=>x.Element("id") != null).Select(x=>x).OrderByDescending(x=>int.Parse(x.Element("id").Value)).Take(5);
```

If you wanted to go a step further you could create an anonymous type from the results like so (I had to copy your spelling error in Description to have it work)

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/test.xml"));
var result = doc.Descendants("post").Where(x => x.Element("id") != null).Select(x => new
{
    id = x.Element("id").Value,
    title = x.Element("title").Value,
    Description = x.Element("Discription").Value,
    dt = x.Element("dt").Value,
    mnt = x.Element("mnt").Value,
    yr = x.Element("yr").Value
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(5);
```

Comment: i never work with linq till now and i don't now how to bind this result with repeater control please can u explain me briefly

Comment: the result is your datasource, so replace `dv` with `result`

Comment: I just added an int.Parse to make the orderby work as expected.

Comment: hey i do this but one thing i wanna to know it is fetching only data from post node i need the data from every node what i have to do ?

Comment: Updated to select the whole post

Comment: see i did this 
 String File = Server.MapPath("~/Data/BlogContent.xml");
        var doc = XDocument.Load(File);
        var result = doc.Descendants("post").Where(x => x.Element("id") != null).Select(x => x.Element("id").Value).OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x)).Take(5);
        Repeater1.DataSource = result;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
 i got this error

 please tell me i never work with linq 
xception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'title'.

Comment: Take out the `String File` part and have the `XDocument.Load()` call the path directly

Comment: I cannot recreate your error on this end, you may need to share more details on what you have. Could it be title missing from a post in the XML?

Comment: okk james let me try first what you tell me then i will tell u the result

Comment: Getting this exception

System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`6[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],

Comment: Update your question to add at the bottom what your code looks like now

Comment: you have errors in your markup. in code after the `new` keyword we create fields in the anonymous type. The names on the *left* are the field names. I corrected the spelling of `Description` for example. Also be sure the case is the same

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you to select TOP 5 records directly from `xmlDocument`.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString);

XmlNodeList xNodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/content/post[position() <= 5]");
```

Now you can iterate over `xNodeList` to fetch particular value inside the `post` tag.

You can also select TOP N records from data table then Linq will be better option

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try loading data into XmlDocument and then by using SelectNodes method create a XmlNode list:

```
XmlDocument Document = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList XNList;
        try
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            Document.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        XNList = Document.SelectNodes("RootNode/Node");
```

This way you can work with List's, and simpli access the first n nodes by their index in the list or by using any loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
            // load xml
        var xmlDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("[XML PATH]");

        // get root with name ArrayOfActivity
        var items = xmlDoc.Elements("ArrayOfActivity").FirstOrDefault();

        // get top 5 
        var top5 = items.Elements().OrderBy(x=>x.Elements("Id")).Take(5);

        // loop children
        foreach (var x in items.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
        }
```

You can then bind the list like this (Taking top5 as the datasource from above) :

```
            // if you want you can bind the list to a datagrid
        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
        dg.DataSource = top5;
        dg.DataBind();
```

To use your example, use the following code

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xd = new System.Xml.Linq.XDocument("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <content> <post> </post> <post> <id>1</id> <title>fds</title> <Discription>fdsafsdf</Discription> <dt>21</dt> <mnt>6</mnt> <yr>2013</yr> </post> </content>");

        // Get all posts
        var items = xd.Elements("posts").OrderBy(x=>x.Elements("[Id]")).Take(5);
```